# Springboot Maven running application on mvn package

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My application is a command line runner menu system that expects input to do anything
`(1. DoThing, 2. DoOtherThing, 3. Exit, etc.)`.

When I run `mvn package`, the application compiles, tests, and runs. The problem is the running part, it hangs the package process because it runs my application which just waits for user input.

If I add some sort of `if(args.length == 0) return;` it works as I want it to, but then when I run my jar, I need to input some useless arg to get my application to run.

Is there a way I can stop this or am I creating my springboot project incorrectly?

Comment: You have messed with the plugin configuration in maven and injected your application to run as a part of the package phase. Don't touch your program, that's just hacking around the problem. Fix your pom.xml

Comment: I would insist on sharing the pom.xml content in terms of your current plugin configurations and their probable versions(which is always good to know).